# Retrieve object from json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm getting a JSON object from my database that looking like this :

```
products = [
    {"ID":1, "CODE":"code1", "DESCRIPTION":"abcd", "PRICE":100},
    {"ID":2, "CODE":"code2", "DESCRIPTION":"efgh", "PRICE":100},
    {"ID":3, "CODE":"code3", "DESCRIPTION":"ijkl", "PRICE":100}
];
```

Then I have a select element with options having text = CODE and value = ID for each product.
Now when user select a product in the dropdown, I want to fill some textboxes with DESCRIPTION and PRICE of the selected product. Is there any built-in function to do something like this :

```
var myObject = products("ID" = selectedValue)
```

?

I'd like to use

```
myObject.DESCRIPTION, myObject.PRICE
```

to fill my textboxes. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.each` utility function:

```
$('select').change(function(){
   var id = this.value;
   $.each(products, function(i, myObject){
      if (myObject.ID === id) {
        $('textarea').val(myObject.DESCRIPTION);
        return false;
      }
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern javascript engines (IE9 and above, node.js and standards compliant browsers) also support the functional list methods for arrays: `map`, `reduce`, and `filter`.

This is a classic case for `filter`:

```
var myObject = products.filter(function(x){return x.ID == selectedValue})[0];
```

For older borwsers you can implement this shim:

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
    Array.prototype.filter = function(callback, myself) {
        if (!myself) myself = this;
        var result = [];
        for (var i=0;i<myself.length;i++) {
            if (callback(myself[i],i,myself)) result.push(myself[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```